# keyup function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a character counter in js but keyup event is not working ???

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countingCharacter(element, maxCount) {
    var countLength = $('#' + element).val().length();
    alert(countLength);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea onkeyup="countingCharacter("storyOutline",100)" onkeypress="countingCharacter("storyOutline",100);" onkeydown="countingCharacter("storyOutline",100)" id="storyOutline" rows="5" class="form-control" name="labinput7" placeholder="Story Outline" required></textarea>
```

Comment: First define `countingCharacter()` function in global scope and nest quotes properly

Comment: or stop using inline-events and add event listeners from your JS code.

Comment: try `onkeyup="countingCharacter('storyOutline',100)"`

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen ,not working......

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any issues related to the functions scope and keep JS code separated from HTML, I'd go with following event binding:

```
$('#storyOutline').on('keyUp', function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length();
  alert(length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onkeyup="countingCharacter("storyOutline",100)"`

`"storyOutline"` will close and open the quotes in `onkeyup`

You could use single quotes inside the double quotes:

`onkeyup="countingCharacter('storyOutline',100)"`

Comment: You'll need to change where the functions are defined too. They are out of scope of the `on*` attributes as the OPs code stands

Answer (score 0):

You can get textarea length using `event.currentTarget.textLength` value

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#storyOutline", function (e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.textLength);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="storyOutline" rows="5" class="form-control" name="labinput7" placeholder="Story Outline" required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
       alert("your pressed the key");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter your name: <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

when you keyup on the text field, you'll find an alert message that you have keyed.

Answer (score -1):

Use single quotes to add arguments to the inline JavaScript functions, so:

```
<textarea onkeyup="countingCharacter('storyOutline')" ... ></textarea>
```

Instead of

```
<textarea onkeyup="countingCharacter("storyOutline")" ...></textarea>
```

---

But **you don't actually need those parameters** (you can keep `maxCount` inside the function's scope). Then access the target (input box element) with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Select its input value and its length.

Here's a working code:

```js
function countingCharacter(maxCount) {
  console.log($(event.target).val().length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea onkeyup="countingCharacter(100)" onkeypress="countingCharacter(100);" onkeydown="countingCharacter(100)" id="storyOutline" rows="5" class="form-control" name="labinput7" placeholder="Story Outline"
  required></textarea>
```

You shouldn't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log` instead.

Comment: @lvan, If I want to use for numbers of text boxes but function should be single how can i implement ??? Do you have anyidea

Comment: @ Ivan ,I have'nt down voted you I respect your answer.